Sturm-Liouville problem: $\frac{d}{dx}\Big(e^{2x}\frac{dy}{dx}\Big)+e^{2x}(1+\lambda)y=0$
I'm trying to solve the Sturm-Liouville problem
$$\frac{d}{dx}\Big(e^{2x}\frac{dy}{dx}\Big)+e^{2x}(1+\lambda)y=0$$
with boundary conditions $y(0)=y(\pi)=0$ but i'm stuck because every reference on SL problem that I've found just show the $y''+\lambda y=0$ example that is pretty straightforward and doesn't explain too much.
I've tried to transform this in $y''+2y'+(1+\lambda)y=0$ but i get only trivial solutions.
I've tried to use the $L[y]=\frac{d}{dx}\Big(p(x)\frac{dy}{dx}\Big)-q(x)y$ operator to get $L[y]=-\lambda e^{2x}y$ but i can't go on.
Can you please give me some hints? Eigenvalues should be $\lambda_n=n^2$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and eigenfunction $\phi_n(x)=c_ne^{-x}\sin(nx)$.

$$\frac{d}{dx}\Big(e^{2x}\frac{dy}{dx}\Big)+e^{2x}(1+\lambda)y=e^{2x}\Big(y''+2y'+(1+\lambda)y \Big)=0$$
$$y''+2y'+(1+\lambda)y=0$$
$$y(x)=c_1e^{-x}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda }\,x)+c_2e^{-x}\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\,x)$$
$y(0)=y(\pi)=0\quad\implies\quad c_2=0$
$$y(x)=c_1e^{-x}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda }\,x)$$
If $\lambda<0$ proceed with hyperbolic functions instead of sinusoidal functions.

I've done some mistakes and got $c_1=0$ and $c_2=0$ for some reasons. Now everything works, thanks a lot.
